# C# MVC4 Requests Failing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having a bit of an issue with HTTP calls in production. Here is the scenario:

We have a desktop app that communicates with the web server via HTTP requests. This works fine with the below blurb of code on both the server and client side in QA. Now we move from an internally hosted IIS to AWS and throw it live (same configuration, IIS7/Server 2016, port 443/80 allowed on AWS for all IPs), it now half works. Users are able to log in and authenticate remotely from the client application, but certain calls fail to even reach the method on the controller (returns a 500 error after hanging for a few seconds, whereas the calls that work go through instantly) in production. I'm having trouble understanding it as I would believe it would fail completely in QA (for either a network issue or something else) and not work in one place but not the next.

DB connectivity is verified (able to pull the user account/authenticate). All external DLLs are up to date (old files are burned each time a new build is pushed to avoid stagnation), verified connectivity on 443/80, other methods on the same controller are working, and everything works in QA.

[New Password Class]

```
[Serializable]
    public class NewPassword
{
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string Location { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string UserPassword { get; set; }

        public int PasswordID { get; set; }
}
```

[Controller Code]
(Controller path is /API/)

```
[HttpPost] // Does not work with or without HttpPost attribute
[ValidateInput(false)] // disabled for testing, did not help
public JsonResult CSCreate(NewPassword Data)
{

}
```

[Client Code]

```
internal static Status CreatePassword(UserAccount Account, Password Credential)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://" + Methods.Session.Connection.ServerName + "/API/CSCreate");
        Request.ContentType = "application/json";
        Request.Method = "POST";
        using (StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(Request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            NewPassword Data = new NewPassword() { UserID = Account.ID, Password = Credential.Text, Username = Credential.Username, Location = Credential.Location, UserPassword = Account.Password, Name = Credential.Name };
            string JSON = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Data);
            SW.Write(JSON);
        }
        HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string Data = SR.ReadToEnd();
            Status EndData = (Status)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Data, typeof(Status));
            if (EndData.ExitCode != 200) return new Status() { ExitCode = 400, ExitMessage = EndData.ExitMessage };
            else return new Status() { ExitCode = 200, ExitMessage = EndData.ExitMessage };
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        return new Status() { ExitCode = 500, ExitMessage = "Unable to update your account. An error occurred. Please try again later." };
    }
}
```

Interestingly enough, the (500) response is mentions a GET method even though "POST" is specified in the request information. Attempting a PUT or GET method errors out (GET for obvious reasons) with a not allowed (which makes sense given the attribute). I'm completely stumped on this one.

Comment: "Interestingly enough, the (500) response is mentions a GET method even though "GET" is specified in the AJAX information". Is that a typo? Sounds like you meant "POST" in the second instance? BTW, none of this is AJAX. An AJAX request describes an asynchronous request made _specifically_ from a browser initiated by JavaScript code, outside the normal page refresh cycle, and has some complexities all of its own that don't apply here. What you're doing here is just a regular HTTP request, spawned by some C# code.

Comment: Correct, it was a typo. And yes, I was having the same issue with an AJAX call from one of the web pages in production as well so I was relating it to that without thinking as I was typing :).

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. What exactly does this 500 say, then? Normally you just get "Internal Server Error" and nothing else. It does rather sound like you need to do some more detailed logging within the server application though, the obvious differentiator is the AWS infrastructure, plus the network in between, so you might have to try and narrow down the problem a bit.

Comment: Are you using load balancing?  If by "certain calls fail"  you mean some users can authenticate and others can not then one server being misconfigured could cause this behavior. Ultimately, if the code works in one environment and not another then it's something external to the code of which people can only guess at. As such, this isn't really a question that can be objectively answered.

Comment: There is no load balancing, it is a direct connection to that single server, mimicking the setup of our internal test server. Every AUTH call succeeds, every of the above reference call fails - both are on the same controller, on the same server. That is what doesn't make sense and seems to be somewhat of a software issue as well.